# PHP Contact Form blank emails

Tags: php, forms

Looks like send.php is being accessed and sending blank emails. Need to make it so send.php doesn't send email, unless the submit button is used on a form. I was told 'isset $_post' would help me, just not clear on how to execute it.

Here's send.php code:

```
    <?php

$recipient  =   'test@test.com';

$email      =   $_REQUEST['Email'];

$subject    =   'Contact Form Submission';

$content    =   "The following has been submitted on your website \n\n";

$redirect   =   'thankyoupage.html';

$user = $_REQUEST['Email'];
$usersubject = "Subject";
$userheaders = "From: test@test.com\n";
$usermessage = "Blah blah blah";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);

foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
    {
        $content .= "$k: $v\n\n";
    }

mail_it(stripslashes($content), $subject, $email, $recipient);

if (isset($_POST['redirect']))
    {
        header("Location:".$_POST['redirect']);
    }
        else
    {
        header("Location: $redirect");
    }

function mail_it($content, $subject, $email, $recipient)
    {

        $headers .= "From: ".$email."\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\n";

        if ($bcc) $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\n"; 

        $headers .= "X-Priority: 0\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: bjm Formmail \n";
        $message = $content."\n\n";

        if( !mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            echo "Sorry - an error occured trying to send the mail";
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: how are you calling send.php?

Comment: <form id="emf-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="send.php" name="form">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check wether the request method was POST. If so, you should send the email:

```
<?php

$recipient  =   'test@test.com';

$email      =   $_REQUEST['Email'];

$subject    =   'Contact Form Submission';

$content    =   "The following has been submitted on your website \n\n";

$redirect   =   'thankyoupage.html';

$user = $_REQUEST['Email'];
$usersubject = "Subject";
$userheaders = "From: test@test.com\n";
$usermessage = "Blah blah blah";


foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
    {
        $content .= "$k: $v\n\n";
    }

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     mail_it(stripslashes($content), $subject, $email, $recipient);
}

if (isset($_POST['redirect']))
    {
        header("Location:".$_POST['redirect']);
    }
        else
    {
        header("Location: $redirect");
    }

function mail_it($content, $subject, $email, $recipient)
    {

        $headers .= "From: ".$email."\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\n";

        if ($bcc) $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\n"; 

        $headers .= "X-Priority: 0\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: bjm Formmail \n";
        $message = $content."\n\n";

        if( !mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            echo "Sorry - an error occured trying to send the mail";
        }

    }

?>
```

This makes it all happen:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     mail_it(stripslashes($content), $subject, $email, $recipient);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\r\n` at the end of header lines. But if you only have one header you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the code is only executed when there is a post request. You can do that by wrapping everything in:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. Think it causes an issue because of the other if statements. Tried doing: <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') : ?> at top, not working though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail, only when someone hits submit button, simply use this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   send_mail();      //and define send mail somewhere else 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your php script:

```
if ($Name == '')
{
    die("<p align='center'><font face='Arial' size='6' color='#FF0000'>Please use our<a href=''> contact form</a> to send a message to us</font></p>");
}
```

add it just after:

```
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email`enter code here`'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));
```

if you are getting blank emails it means someone is running the `action="contact.php"` script from the browser like `www.yousite.com/contactsend.php`

this code above will stop it